# ASP.NET MVC 3 upload file maximum size

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I am trying to upload large files using ASP.NET Web API controller

1. I am able to upload until 2 GB.
2. But for more than 2 GB I am unable to upload.
3. Is this a limitation of the [Web API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework#Apache_License_2.0_release) controller and ASP.NET?
4. Should I make any configuration changes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it has been voted for and completed as of .NET 4.5, see *[Maximum upload size in ASP.NET is 2 GB. Increase it](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general/suggestions/2642879-maximum-upload-size-in-asp-net-is-2gb-increase-it?tracking_code=5805b1d13655be23d0395513447ba9f7)*. However, it needs to be resolved in IIS 8.0, see *[Please, share how to upload files larger then 2 GB (without splitting) on IIS 8.0 using ASP.NET 4.5?](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/41199-general-asp-net/suggestions/3122276-please-share-how-to-upload-files-larger-then-2gb-)*.

Otherwise, you might have to look at third-party (paid, open source) solutions for a more elegant approach of uploading the large files in chunks (with a progress bar indicator, etc.).